# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200 In Jhipster application

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, jhipster, stomp, sockjs

I am trying to connect to websocket in my existing Jhipster application which is build using Java spring and Angular 8. At the time of creation of the project I didn't select the websocket option and now there is a need to implement the websockets in the project. I took the help from "https://www.jhipster.tech/using-websockets/" and tried to implement the same solution but I am getting the handshake failure message.
I am using STOMP and sockJS for in websockets.
Please let me know what could be the reasons for handshake failure.

Here is the websocket configuration.java file.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler;

import hr.nic.vc.security.AuthoritiesConstants;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.http.server.*;

import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.server.*;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config)
  {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    //config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry
   registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/websocket/blog").setHandshakeHandler(defaultHandshakeHandler())
        .setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
  }
  
  @Bean
  public HandshakeInterceptor httpSessionHandshakeInterceptor() {
      return new HandshakeInterceptor() {

          @Override
          public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
              if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
                  ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
                  attributes.put(IP_ADDRESS, servletRequest.getRemoteAddress());
              }
              return true;
          }

          @Override
          public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {

          }
      };
  }

  private DefaultHandshakeHandler defaultHandshakeHandler() {
      return new DefaultHandshakeHandler() {
          @Override
          protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
              Principal principal = request.getPrincipal();
              if (principal == null) {
                  Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                  authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ANONYMOUS));
                  principal = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("WebsocketConfiguration", "anonymous", authorities);
              }
              return principal;
          }
      };
  }
  
}
```

And this is the websocket security file.

```
public class WebsocketSecurityConfiguration extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
      protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages)
      {
        messages.nullDestMatcher().authenticated().simpDestMatchers("/topic/blog")
            .authenticated()
            // matches any destination that starts with /topic/
            // (i.e. cannot send messages directly to /topic/)
            // (i.e. can’t subscribe to /topic/messages/* to get messages which is sent to
            // /topic/messages-user)
            .simpDestMatchers("/topic/**").authenticated();
            // message types other than MESSAGE and SUBSCRIBE
            //.simpTypeMatchers(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE, SimpMessageType.SUBSCRIBE).denyAll()
            // catch all
            //.anyMessage().denyAll();
      }
    /**
     * Disables CSRF for Websockets.
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the connect method which is called after authentication for connecting the websocket.

```
connect():void {
    console.log("connect called"); //eslint-disable-line
    // build absolute path, websocket doesn't fail during deploying with a context path
    let url = '/websocket/blog';
    url = this.location.prepareExternalUrl(url);
    const authToken = this.authServerProvider.getToken();
    if (authToken) {
      url += '?access_token=' + authToken;
    }
    const socket = new SockJS(url);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    const headers = {};
    this.stompClient.connect(headers, () => {
        console.log("this is inside stompclient connect connect"); //eslint-disable-line
      this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/blog', data => {
          console.log("This inside subscription"); //eslint-disable-line
        this.listenerObserver.next(JSON.parse(data.body));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Authorization token is passed with the correct value. Hence there is no error in authorization.
Please let me know if anything else is required.
I am stuck at this point for quite a long time now.

**Error:**

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/websocket/blog/587/mklduqvp/websocket?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJoYXJkZWVwc2h1a2xhMDhAbmljLmluIiwiYXV0aCI6IlJPTEVfRU1QTE9ZRUUiLCJleHAiOjE2MDUyNDUwNjd9.DJ2HITaVAiaphd2yg3yPAiLrLI4n8MjszjBasC3zOHrC-73mFdltDPEYHihY16VzPv0rh6EYLj84zCBv37TDNA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Comment: Have you tried generating a new project with same settings as old one and copy the configuration?

Comment: Yes i have tried that. Still no luck. Same error as above.

Comment: Newly generated project works fine.
I an trying to add websocket configuration to the existing project. Also i have updated the error. Please have a look

Comment: The version of Jhipster is same for new and old project. Yes i checked the server side logs there were no errors only client side showed this error.
I did not run the server in debugger as both the projects are quite different.

Comment: Debugger will show you execution in the message broker which is not your code so it is the same between both projects, only its initialization should be different and trigger  different behavior. Server logs are probably not in DEBUG level for `org.springframework.web.socket`, so you can't see what's going on  to comapre.

Answer (score 0):

In your DefaultHandshakeHandler, can you try to annotate @Bean and set to public.

```
@Bean
public DefaultHandshakeHandler defaultHandshakeHandler() {
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i have already tried that.
Still getting the same error.